# Ruby and Net::SSH Interfacing with a interactive command line application

Tags: ruby, ssh

I have an interactive command-line application running on an embedded Linux machine. After the application is launched, it accepts commands from stdin and replies with information on stdout and stderr. I talk to the application via a ssh-terminal (I use Tera-Term on my Windows 7 machine).
Now I would like to replace the ssh-terminal with a ruby application using Net::SSH. The ruby application running on PC is supposed to send commands to the embedded Linux application and read back the replies.

For testing I wrote the following embedded application:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    char line[256];
    for (i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++ ){
        printf("arg%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    while(1){
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        printf("You sent: %s", line);
        fflush(stdout);
        if(!strncmp(line,"quit",4)) break;
    }
    printf("Signing off. Good Bye!\n");
    return(0);
}
```

On the PC side the my ruby script goes as follows:

```
    require 'net/ssh'

HOST='192.168.1.10'
USER='root'
PASS='root'

t0 = Time.now

Net::SSH.start(HOST, USER, :password => PASS) do |ssh|

  channel = ssh.open_channel do |ch|

    ch.exec "/media/card/test2.elf 1 2 3 " do |ch, success|

      raise "could not execute command" unless success

      ch.on_data do |c, data| # handler for remote's stdout
        $stdout.print data
        puts"                 t,receive = #{Time.now-t0} "
      end

      ch.on_extended_data do |c, type, data| # handler for remote's stderr
        $stderr.print data
      end

      ch.on_close do  # handler for remote's exit
        puts "done!"
      end
    end

  end

  t = Thread.new{
    # send data to remote's stdin
    %w(one two three quit).each do |word|
      sleep 0.5
      puts "Sending: #{word}    "
      puts"                 t,send = #{Time.now-t0} "
      channel.send_data word+"\n"
    end
  }  

  ssh.loop(0.05)

end
```

Here is what I get so far:

```
    Sending: one    
                 t,send = 1.954 
arg1: 1
arg2: 2
arg3: 3
You sent: one
                 t,receive = 1.984 
Sending: two    
                 t,send = 2.454 
You sent: two
                 t,receive = 2.494 
Sending: three    
                 t,send = 2.954 
You sent: three
                 t,receive = 3.004 
Sending: quit    
                 t,send = 3.454 
You sent: quit
                 t,receive = 3.514 
Signing off. Good Bye!
                 t,receive = 3.514 
done!
```

This mostly works, but one problem I haven't been able to solve yet.
My expectation is that the initial output of the remote application (3 lines starting with `arg1: 1`) are displayed immediately. However this is not the case. It seems that only after sending the first command, I get all the output data up to `You sent: one`.

How can I get the initial output?

Additional information:

ruby 1.9.3p550 (2014-10-27) [i386-mingw32]

net-ssh (2.9.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After abandoning this for quite some time, I finally found the problem. Obviously just a silly oversight of mine. The problem was in the C program, I simply forgot to flush stdout after writing the command line arguments.
Here's the version that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    char line[256];
    for (i = 1 ; i < argc ; i++ ){
        printf("arg%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    fflush(stdout); // this line added to send command line arguments
    while(1){
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        printf("You sent: %s", line);
        fflush(stdout);
        if(!strncmp(line,"quit",4)) break;
    }
    printf("Signing off. Good Bye!\n");
    return(0);
}
```